PyTorch RuntimeError: No operator found for memory_efficient_attention_forward with torch.float16 inputs on CPU
I am working with a PyTorch model (AutoModelForCausalLM) using the transformers library and encountering a RuntimeError related to tensor types and operator support. Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import torch
import requests
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer

# Load tokenizer and model
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained('lmsys/vicuna-7b-v1.5')
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    'THUDM/cogvlm-chat-hf',
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,  # Using torch.float16
    low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
    trust_remote_code=True
).eval()

def generate(query: str, img_url: str, max_length: int = 2048) -> str:
    image = Image.open(requests.get(img_url, stream=True).raw).convert('RGB')
    display(image)

    # Generate token inputs
    inputs = model.build_conversation_input_ids(tokenizer, query=query, history=[], images=[image], template_version='vqa')

    # Convert tensors to appropriate types
    input_ids = inputs['input_ids'].unsqueeze(0).to(torch.long)
    token_type_ids = inputs['token_type_ids'].unsqueeze(0).to(torch.long)
    attention_mask = inputs['attention_mask'].unsqueeze(0).to(torch.float16)
    images = [[inputs['images'][0].to(torch.float16)]]

    inputs = {
        'input_ids': input_ids,
        'token_type_ids': token_type_ids,
        'attention_mask': attention_mask,
        'images': images,
    }
    
    gen_kwargs = {"max_length": max_length, "do_sample": False}
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model.generate(**inputs, **gen_kwargs)
        outputs = outputs[:, input_ids.shape[1]:]
        return tokenizer.decode(outputs[0])

query = 'Describe this image in detail'
img_url = 'https://i.ibb.co/x1nH9vr/Slide1.jpg'
generate(query, img_url)

Above code throws throws the following error:
NotImplementedError: No operator found for `memory_efficient_attention_forward` with inputs:
     query       : shape=(1, 1226, 16, 112) (torch.float16)
     key         : shape=(1, 1226, 16, 112) (torch.float16)
     value       : shape=(1, 1226, 16, 112) (torch.float16)
     attn_bias   : <class 'NoneType'>
     p           : 0.0
`ck_decoderF` is not supported because:
    device=cpu (supported: {'cuda'})
    operator wasn't built - see `python -m xformers.info` for more info
`ckF` is not supported because:
    device=cpu (supported: {'cuda'})
    operator wasn't built - see `python -m xformers.info` for more info

I'm trying to use torch.float16 tensors with my PyTorch model on CPU (device=cpu). The model is loaded with torch.float16 using AutoModelForCausalLM from the transformers library. However, I encounter the NotImplementedError stating that the memory_efficient_attention_forward operator isn't supported on CPU with torch.float16.
Is there a way to make memory_efficient_attention_forward work with torch.float16 on CPU? Are there alternative approaches or configurations I should consider to resolve this issue?

I am trying to run this on a MacBook PRO with Intel Core i7 processor.


As a first step I would recommend profiling your module. There is detailed documentation on the same
Pytorch Profiling

You can try some of the things mentioned in the documentation
If it does not help, you can provide the profiler output and then someone can help you better

